# Invited for a screening interview for one position, but a slightly better fit for a different position

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-search, multiple-jobs

I applied for position A in a company. I meet about 1/3 of the qualifications for the job *explicitly*, but have a strong background that would make me a good candidate nonetheless. I got an email asking to set up a screening interview with their HR recruiter, as they believed my resume might make me a good fit for the position.

Some time after applying to position A, position B in the same company opened up. The company is fairly small, so it is likely that the same person is reviewing the applications, or is at least familiar with any applications that come in. I am a much stronger fit all across the board for position B. I would prefer position A for career reasons, but in the end, my goal is to work at this company (they do incredible work), whichever position that is.

How should I approach this with the HR recruiter? Should I send an email referencing the position, in advance of the interview? Should I just mention it in the interview? Or should I apply to the position and perhaps mention this in the cover letter?

I do not want to come across as “wishy-washy,” as if I’ll take whatever job I can get, but I also want them to know that I want to work at their company and have a skill set that may be applicable for job B as well. Overall, I’d like to take the route that results in *the highest chances that I will be offered a position at this company*.

Comment: When is this upcoming meeting with the recruiter for position A?

Comment: It is tomorrow. My gut feeling right now is to submit the application for position B without commentary, and simply mention it at the interview.

Comment: BTW, welcome to The Workplace, please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with the site :)

Answer (score 1):

Like you well suspected in comments, given that your interview is tomorrow I would surely ask about position B somewhere during the interview, where it's appropriate (perhaps more towards the end, or if you see an opening, or the moment they ask you for questions or comments).

It's even a possibility that they will bring the subject up by themselves at some point during the interview, or introduce this other role or perhaps another you aren't aware of, without you having to mention it first.

I would also suggest you submit/apply to position B if it is also of your interest and you feel you are fit for the role. If you have all the requirements for application lined up then go ahead apply and also ask tomorrow when meeting. If you don't have all the requirements for application lined up then start gathering them so you already have some steps done for when you get a definite answer from them tomorrow.

Comment: In a small company, after bringing up B, and saying that you might also be a good fit for that position as well, you can ask if they require a separate formal application for that.  At a small firm, that might not be necessary.